# TikZ - Node style depending on node value [foreach + ifthenelse]

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

Into a tikzpicture, I'd like to apply different styles to nodes depending on their values.
For example, in a list of integers, I'd like to color the node in red or in blue.

This is only a test for a bigger project, but an answer on this should help anyway.

The following code is working:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{nums}{{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,10}
        {
        \pgfmathrandomitem{\choice}{nums}
        \ifthenelse{\choice<5}
            {
            \node[circle, fill=blue!50] at (\x,0) {\choice};
            }
            {
            \node[circle,fill=red!50] at (\x,0) {\choice};
            }
        }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But, what I'd like to be able to do is creating a node style, depending on the value of the node. This way, I could add more cases and only use the \node line once.
I tried the simpliest way to achieve that, but it doesn't work:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{nums}{{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,10}
        {
        \pgfmathrandomitem{\choice}{nums}
        \def\clr{\ifthenelse{\choice<5}{blue!50}{red!50}}
        \node[circle, fill=\clr] at (\x,0) {\choice};
        }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

In fine, What I'd like to have is a series of ifthenelse into a tikzstyle.
This didn't work either. Seems that \ifthenelse does not comply with every TikZ structure...

Thanks in advance if you know a way to help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pgf/Tikz has its own `if-then-else` constructs, among othe mathematical operators. See section *95.2 Syntax for Mathematical Expressions: Operators*  of the manual.

What you proposed in you second snippet can actuallay be achieved with the following script.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\tikzset{
    conditionalcolor/.style={circle,fill=#1}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{nums}{{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,10}{
            \pgfmathrandomitem{\choice}{nums}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\col}{ifthenelse(\choice<5,"blue!50","red!50")}
            \node[conditionalcolor=\col] at (\x,0) {\choice};
        }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT** Here is a code where the random number is generated in an interval of integers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    conditionalcolor/.style={circle,fill=#1}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,10}{
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\choice}{random(0,9)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\col}{ifthenelse(\choice<5,"blue!50","red!50")}
            \node[conditionalcolor=\col] at (\x,0) {\choice};
        }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: off-topic: I expect that after each compilation the result will be different, but it is not. Why?

Comment: @Zarko, `\choice` is selected randomly in the list, so it should be different

Comment: But  it is not.  At first compiling selection is random, but after then it is frozen. I test with TikZ 3.1.5b.  Interestingly, If I repeat images, each images has different selection of numbers, but after first compilation they are not changes.

Comment: @Zarko There seems to be a new feature in our new LaTeX installations. This has nothing to do with the specifics of the above code. If I add `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\irnd}{int(100*rnd)}
 \typeout{\irnd}` I get always the same number on my new TeXLive installation. I am pretty sure this did not happen on TeXLive2019, where I had to use `\pgfmathsetseed` to "freeze" my random numbers.

Comment: @Zarko, I am sorry, I totally missed the meaning of your first comment. I actually have the same issue on my miktex. It is a surprising behavior indeed. I played a bit with `\pgfmathsetseed` too and it changes the results. But it feels like the random sequence generator is sort of slow. If you wait a bit it will change the sequence it seems

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, thank you very much for explanation. It seems that the same was happen with MikTeX.

Comment: @BambOo So many thanks, I'll try and implement this in my bigger project. I didn't know about the inhouse TikZ if-then-else constructs. Always fine to learn more.

Comment: You can copy this from the preamble of the `tikzlings` package: `\ifluatex
  \let\pdfrandomseed\randomseed
\fi

\ifxetex
  \pgfmathsetseed{\time}
\else
  \pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}
\fi`