# Ifthenelse - Comparing strings (one inferior to another)

Tags: tikz-pgf, ifthenelse

This topic is following [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/540616/tikz-node-style-depending-on-node-value-foreach-ifthenelse), which was marvelously answered by BambOo yesterday.

Now for a step beyond into this project.

Let's admit I want to put a list of letters (or words) on a 6 columns grid and stylize them depending on their content.

In the following example, I displayed a simple alphabet, and a `[count=\i]` into the loop, but I'd like to be able to compare directly the node content, i.e. something like `ifthenelse(\l<"J", nodeone, nodetwo)`.
Is there any simple way to do that?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\usepackage{ifthen}


\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}


\tikzstyle{nodeone}=[circle, fill=cyan!50!yellow,text=purple,opacity=1,minimum height=30]
\tikzstyle{nodetwo}=[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=5, fill=orange!50!red,text=cyan,opacity=1,minimum height=30]
\tikzstyle{nodethree}=[star,star points=7,star point ratio=0.8, fill=red!50!blue,text=orange,opacity=1,minimum height=30]



\def\LX{2} \def\LY{3} \def\ncol{6} % dimensions of the grid
\def\firstlim{8} \def\secondlim{17}

\foreach \l [count=\i from 0] in {A,...,Z}
    {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\nodestyl}
        {
        ifthenelse(\i<\firstlim,"nodeone",
            ifthenelse(\i<\secondlim,"nodetwo","nodethree")
        }%

    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\result{\i/\ncol}
    \node[\nodestyl] at ({Mod(\i,\ncol)*\LX},-\result*\LY) {\sf \Large \textbf{\l}};
    }


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: The 6 column grid]

I already looked into `etoolbox` to find something that could help, and I found a way to test if strings are equal : `\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\l}{A}{\nodeone}{nodetwo}`, but not yet a way to test if string1 is inferior to string2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do such comparisons with `\pdf@strcmp` from the `pdftexcmds` package. I've tested the following code with pdfTeX, XeTeX and LuaTeX—all of these support the command. `\pdf@strcmp` expands to `-1`, `0` or `1` depending on whether the first string compares strictly less, equal to or strictly greater than the second string (ASCII is certainly supported; for the rest, I don't know—this might be engine-dependent).

Don't use `\tikzstyle`, it is obsolete; instead, use `\tikzset` or the optional argument of `tikzpicture` (see below). Prefer using the `font` option to define the font to be used in Ti*k*Z nodes and never use `\sf` with LaTeX: it is a plain TeX font command, not LaTeX. Better use `\sffamily` or `\textsf`—these are LaTeX font selection commands.

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

\makeatletter
% Expand #1 once before comparing it to #2
\newcommand*{\mystrcmp}[2]{%
  \expandafter\pdf@strcmp\expandafter{#1}{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  nodeone/.style={circle, fill=cyan!50!yellow,text=purple,opacity=1,
                  minimum height=30},
  nodetwo/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=5,
                  fill=orange!50!red,text=cyan,opacity=1,minimum height=30},
  nodethree/.style={star,star points=7,star point ratio=0.8,
                    fill=red!50!blue,text=orange,opacity=1,minimum height=30},
  ]

% Dimensions of the grid
\newcommand*{\LX}{2} \newcommand*{\LY}{3} \newcommand*{\ncol}{6}

\foreach \l [count=\i from 0] in {A,...,Z}
  {
    \edef\myNodestyle{%
      \ifnum\mystrcmp{\l}{I}=-1   % space intended
        nodeone%
      \else
        \ifnum\mystrcmp{\l}{R}=-1 % space intended
          nodetwo%
        \else
          nodethree%
        \fi
      \fi
    }

    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\result}{\i/\ncol}
    \node[\myNodestyle, font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries]
      at ({Mod(\i,\ncol)*\LX}, -\result*\LY) {\l};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful, thanks a lot, frougon!
I'm not familiar with this "expansion"system, I read a lot about it and still don't figure exactly what it means. Another subject I might learn about. I'm on a strict "user level" with LaTeX, not yet able to dig into the real coding. Anyway, your solution is plain and simple to understand and to use.

Comment: An improvement I'd like to add to this is to be able to compare the argument to a predefined list of words. All these little things that are so easy in python or any coding language and that are very hard to achieve in LaTeX (which is not really made for, I have to admit).

Comment: 1) On expansion. Short answer: read the TeXbook (if you have time and want to understand, I'm serious!). There are two very important mechanisms in TeX: expansion replaces tokens by other tokens; execution performs “other things” such as adding a box or glue item to the current horizontal, vertical or math list, shiping out a new page, etc. These are very different. Expansion is what replaces a macro by its definition, but not only: `\the` and `\string` are not macros (they are primitives) but they *expand* to other tokens. Expansion occurs recursively in several contexts. One of these ...

Comment: ... is when TeX is reading a 〈number〉. This is the case on either side of the comparison operator when using `\ifnum`, and that's what we rely on in `\mystrcmp`. `\expandafter` triggers one expansion step after skipping over the next token. It doesn't trigger execution. Execution happens when unexpandable tokens such as `\hbox` or `\def`, or `\edef`, etc. reach TeX's stomach. 2) On string manipulation. LaTeX doesn't deal with “strings” like Python. It deals with token lists. A character token not only has a charcode but also a catcode. This is like a second dimension.

Comment: So, it can't be as simple as in Python for manipulating “strings“ in full generality (how do you compare `abc` all-in-catcode-11 to `abc` all-in-catcode 12 or to `\textit{abc}`?). One of the reasons is as you said: not the original purpose of TeX. Other reasons are probably age, the second dimension I mentioned (catcodes) + the fact that TeX is a macro language. But if you understand TeX well enough, `expl3` provides great high-level tools that allow programming more or less like in a “traditional” programming language.

Comment: If you ask another question about your compare-to-items-in-a-list, I'm sure it will be answered (feel free to ping me here). Note: if you've studied regular expressions, `expl3` has a very impressive regular expression library (`l3regex`) that allows one to match (a) control sequence tokens and (b) character tokens not only based on their charcodes but also on their catcodes (the “second dimension” I mentioned). The last time I used it wasn't earlier than [today](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/540892/73317) (see *Alternate implementation*).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this comprehensive answer. A lot to learn, indeed. Very nice from you to offer your help. I'm grateful.